# Error using install_github for statsr package

Tags: r, installation, devtools

I'm trying to install the companion R package for a Coursera course, with the following commands:

```
library(devtools)
install_github("StatsWithR/statsr")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  Couldn't resolve host name
```

Bet the error is due to the firewall, because at home (where I have no firewall, but exactly the same versions of R and RStudio) I can install flawlessly. Is it possible to fix it? Otherwise, since I've been able to download the package from Github on my pc, how do I install the package manually?

Comment: used something like this? `library(httr)`, `with_config(use_proxy(...)` or `set_config(...) and then `install_github(...))`

Answer (score 0):

Please change you **DNS** to public one.
You can try Google **DNS (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4)** .
It worked fine for me.

[Click here to see how to set public DNS](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Answer (score 0):

to solve this problem you have to install these packages which worked for me.

```
install.packages("devtools")

install.packages("dplyr")

install.packages("rmarkdown")

install.packages("ggplot2")

install.packages("broom")

install.packages("gridExtra")

install.packages("shiny")

install.packages("cubature")

library(devtools)

install_github("StatsWithR/statsr")
```

or use this

```
install.packages(data.table)
devtools::install_github("arunsrinivasan/cran.stats")
```

Comment: Installed the suggested list of packages works for me. If you are asked to actualize any other program skip that step, it did not work and had to start all over.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to install Rtools first and then run the commands.
https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/